# Which type of wait should be used in selenium webdriver for buttons, text boxes and link text

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am working on automation of web application. For finding element on new page I am using Thread.sleep wait. But Want to know where shall implicit, explicit, elementToBePresent, elementToBeClickable waits to be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. Very comprehensive.

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html